# Whats 'T' at the end in SBCL

Tags: output, lisp, common-lisp

I am new at SBCL programming and I ran a simple Addition program:

```
    (defvar a)
    (defvar b)
    (defvar c)
    (defvar d)
    (write-line "Enter A:")
    (setf a (read))
    (write-line "Enter B:")
    (setf b (read))
    (format t "~D + ~D = ~D~%" a b (+ a b))
```

Output:

```
    * (load "lisp_calculator.lisp")
    Enter A:
    12
    Enter B:
    12
    A + B = 24
    T   <--------- Whats This
    *
```

That 'T' is no any trouble to me but i am just curious.

I was thinking to make a multi threading program which will parallely do arithmetic operations so i am using SBCL and not CLISP. am on Kali Linux 2.0

Comment: It's the return value from `LOAD`, telling you that the file was succesfully loaded.

Comment: oh.... is that so.... Thank you very much...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Lisp every function returns/evaluates to a value. `T` here is the return value of `load` and it generally indicates `true`.

From [Common Lisp the Language](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node9.html):

> Any data object other than nil is construed to be Boolean 'not false', that is, 'true'. The symbol t is conventionally used to mean 'true' when no other value is more appropriate. When a function is said to 'return false' or to 'be false' in some circumstance, this means that it returns nil. However, when a function is said to 'return true' or to 'be true'' in some circumstance, this means that it returns some value other than nil, but not necessarily t.